# How to remove mystartsearch.com from browsers

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, hijack

Today, my sister accidentally downloaded an adware/spyware into my PC. Now, every-time I open up any browsers, I will see mystartsearch.com homepage. I tried all the best I can based on my knowledge using tools like autoruns, process explorer, and etc. I have found it's program file inside program files folder and deleted it. I also reset my web browsers setting and remove suspicious plugins. And also, do checking for suspicious task via task manager and process explorer. But, when I start the browser I still see mystartsearch.com homepage.

How can I totally remove it? Why is it still appear in all my browsers?

Comment: Check browser shortcuts, they may have been manipulated to start with that page.

Comment: [Remove MyStartSearch.com redirect (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/mystartsearch-com-removal/)

Answer (score 0):

You may search and look for your question first, I'm pretty sure there are some guides on superuser ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/802210/unable-to-uninstall-or-remove-adware-browser-shop-from-browser) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/639459/how-to-restore-firefox-tabs-after-removing-adware)) about removing adware.

Also have a look at global search and compare products out there. My **personal** solution is Bitdefender's [Adware Removal Tool for PC](http://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/adware-removal-tool-for-pc.html) which free and working fine in most cases.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.techsupportall.com/how-to-remove-mystartsearch-com-homepage-removal-help/) is a tutorial. Also, delete any shortcuts, as the may have edited variables.
In summary, you need to remove mysearch start from your programs in the control panel, and delete all shortcuts to the infected web browsers,as they may be hijacked.

Comment: Please summarize the content from link, otherwise it's liable to be deleted. Link only answers are bad because if the site goes down, your answer becomes useless as well